# How to move files from subfolders with certain extension to different subfolder

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have tens of thousands `.jpg`'s in folders like `.\[date]\jpg` , for example:

```
.\2018_03_01\jpg
.\2018_03_02\jpg
```

...and so on.

I need to move them one step backwards, i.e.

```
.\2018_03_01\jpg\*.jpg
```

...to

```
.\2018_03_01\*.jpg
```

...and so on.

All of those date-named folders don't contain the `jpg` subfolder these occasions should be dealt with.

I suppose this can be done with `XCopy` or traditional `.bat` batch, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command **XCOPY** is for **copying** files and entire directories and not for **moving** files.

The solution is using a **FOR** loop in a command prompt window. There is no need for a batch file.

Open a command prompt window in the directory containing the subdirectories `2018_03_01` and `2018_03_02` and run following command line:

```
@for /D %I in (*) do @if exist "%I\jpg\*.jpg" echo Move files from %I\jpg ... & move "%I\jpg\*.jpg" "%I\" & rd "%I\jpg"
```

This **FOR** command line processes each non hidden subdirectory in current directory.

For each subdirectory an **IF** condition is executed to check existence of any *.jpg file in subdirectory `jpg` of current date subdirectory.

On true condition first an information is output with **ECHO** telling you what happens next. Then the command **MOVE** is executed to move the JPEG files from subdirectory `jpg` one level up in directory hierarchy and last command **RD** is executed to delete subdirectory `jpg` if it is empty now.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rd /?`

See also [Single line with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of `&` used twice in the command line.